# how can i check the whether data is updated or not with isDirty event or else event or method? in Javascript extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to check the one of these fields which are ' Adet', 'toplam' whether they are updated or not when button is clicked  but i dont know how can i do it? thanks

//regarding fields

```
{
    header: dil('Adet'),
    width: 30,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'adet',
    editor: new Ext.form.NumberField({
        enableKeyEvents : true,
        allowBlank: false,
        allowNegative: false,
        style: 'text-align:left'


    })
},{
    header: dil('Toplam'),
    width: 30,
    sortable: true,
    renderer: function(v, params, record){
        return Ext.util.Format.usMoney(record.data.fiyat * record.data.adet);
    },

    dataIndex: 'toplam',
    summaryType: 'totalCost',
    summaryRenderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney

}



 // check area
   handler: function(){
       //commente alındı
       // fileGrid_yp_is.el.mask(dil('Lütfen Bekleyiniz...'), 'x-mask-loading');

          var il_id = Ext.getCmp('il_global25').getValue();
          var sap_no = Ext.getCmp('ila-sapno-id25').getValue();
           if(il_id == '' || sap_no == '' // this area code will be added) {
                Ext.Msg.alert(dil("Dikkat"),dil("Lütfen zorunlu alanları doldurunuz"));
                return false;
            }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive this with the **[dirtychange](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-event-dirtychange)** event. The second param will be true if the value has been changed or false if not. The event will also only fire once a state change.

A second variant is the [isModified(fieldName)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-isModified) method of a model. It will return true ich the submitted field has been changed since the last load or commit.

Comment: thanks, but I cannot use dirtychange event so I don't understand how to do it?

Comment: @user1702486 Well I extended my post with a second variant. Based on your example I can't give you any further advice cause it is totally unclear from which scope you are calling the function. Please provide more information on that part.

Comment: Try with 'datachanged' listener for the store. Make a flag and appropiately modify the flag value in this listener.

Comment: @Jai Datachanged will also fire if data gets loaded from the server which makes it less usable for the described case.